# Reloading part of the page and changing the URL

Tags: c#, url, razor, model-view-controller

I'm doing a project in MVC and I want to generate part of a page and change the URL.

Here is part of the code:

```
<div id="body">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 30px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Indexação de documentos clínicos</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar por..." id="contId" value="@ViewBag.searchModel.SearchTerm"/>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();">Procurar</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 150px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="list-group" id="contribution">@Html.Partial("ResultsPartial")</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="pagination" class="col-md-12">
                @if (ViewBag.searchModel.TotalResults != 0 && ViewBag.searchModel.NumberOfPages>1)
                {
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        @{
                            for (int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.searchModel.NumberOfPages; i++)
                            {
                                <li><a href="#" id="@i" onclick="changePage(@i);">@i</a></li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a html related to `search view`. When I search something I want to reload just the part of the page who show the results and page numbers (links), if needed. Still, I need to save the URL with the page and the search keyword.
Is there a way to do this without reloading all pages?

This is the controller (reloads all page for now):

```
public ActionResult Search(string id, int page)
    {

        searchModel.SearchTerm = id;
        searchModel.Page = page - 1;
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> res = new ContributionsController().GetContributions(searchModel.SearchTerm, searchModel.StartPage, searchModel.Rows);
        searchModel.Results = res;
        if (res.Count==0)
        {
            searchModel.Reset();
            return View("Index");
        }
        searchModel.TotalResults = Convert.ToInt32(res[0]["total_num"]);
        ViewBag.searchModel = searchModel;

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Thanks =)

Comment: if you don't reload page, you can use ajax call action in controller

Comment: but with AJAX call can I change url too?

Comment: I think we can new action, and data return is Json Type

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. It loads part of the page but the url doesnt change. Can you give me a little example? Maybe im doing something wrong. btw Thanks =)